# Fix the big crack on wood post

Tags: wood, deck

We moved in a house at Dallas area and the wood post at my deck has a big crack in it, I read some post that it is normal, but if I don't treat it, will it keep cracking. Thanks a lot of any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal for that type of post in the south.  To treat the wood and not affect the color use a linseed based sealer.

The applicator I've linked to is only intended as a reference as there are several manufacturers and styles of rough surface applicators.

[Linseed Oil](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Klean-Strip-1-gal-Boiled-Linseed-Oil-GLO45/100203798)

[Linseed Oil](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Jasco-128-fl-oz-Slow-to-Dissolve-Linseed-Oil/50298069)

[Rough Surface Applicator](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Mr-LongArm-Woodmates-Exterior-Stain-Pad/3658056)

Comment: would you provide a product link you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the links.

Comment: Second two links are dead.  Also, seems like a squirt bottle might be good for getting the oil into the deeper cracks.

Comment: Links have been updated.

Comment: Probably worth noting that oil won't cause the cracks to disappear - just slow wood movement so they don't get much worse.